# Can Eclipse mosquitto MQTT broker be used over LAN? Why does this configuration time out for remote connections?

Tags: windows, linux-networking

Is it possible to use Eclipse mosquitto MQTT broker over a LAN using the lease ranges of 192.x.x.x? I claim this is not possible. I present the following as evidence that this does not work. Hopefully, some brave person will appear and prove me wrong.

mosquitto is running on the local machine at IP 192.168.2.1 (OS=Linux) The remote computer is 192.168.2.104 (OS=Win10) . It will attempt to publish to the broker but time out.

Contents of mosquitto.conf

```
user mosquit
listener 8883 0.0.0.0
protocol mqtt
log_dest syslog
log_type all
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/plaintext
```

Three ssh sessions are established. One for tail’ing the broker’s log. One for a subscriber. And another for a publisher. mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub are run locally and the payload is delivered correctly. But these are all local communications. We want to publish from the remote *.104 computer. At the very least we want to see something happen on the log at *.1. Rejection messages, something, anything. But all attempts time out. Note the connected subscriber at 57734.

```
$ netstat -tp
netstat: showing only processes with your user ID
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:8883        192.168.2.1:57734       ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:ssh         192.168.2.104:51723     ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:57734       192.168.2.1:8883        ESTABLISHED 4365/mosquitto_sub
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:ssh         192.168.2.104:51569     ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0    140 192.168.2.1:ssh         192.168.2.104:51765     ESTABLISHED -
```

The listener appears on port 8883

```
$ netstat -tulpn
netstat: showing only processes with your user ID
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 :::53                   :::*
```

The firewall on the Linux *.1 is set to allow 8883 and 1883 by whitelist.

```
~# iptables -L
Chain TRUSTED_IP_INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             source IP range 192.168.2.102-192.168.2.106 tcp dpt:1883
RETURN     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             source IP range 192.168.2.102-192.168.2.106 udp dpt:1883
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             source IP range 192.168.2.102-192.168.2.106 tcp dpt:8883
RETURN     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             source IP range 192.168.2.102-192.168.2.106 udp dpt:8883
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW
-
```

The firewall on the remote computer *.104 is completely disabled.

[image: Disabled firewall in win10]

Successful **local** pubs and subs appear in the /var/log/mosquitto.log

```
2022-09-22T18:33:11.758357-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: New connection from 192.168.2.1 on port 8883.
2022-09-22T18:33:11.764226-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: New client connected from 192.168.2.1 as mosq-uQu5OKrc9nYuqKEN8A (p2, c1, k60, u'bridgechirp').
2022-09-22T18:33:11.766554-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: No will message specified.
2022-09-22T18:33:11.766982-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: Sending CONNACK to mosq-uQu5OKrc9nYuqKEN8A (0, 0)
2022-09-22T18:33:11.780655-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: Received PUBLISH from mosq-uQu5OKrc9nYuqKEN8A (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'newsEvent', ... (11 bytes))
2022-09-22T18:33:11.781235-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: Sending PUBLISH to mosq-eoozTCsMlL1dIFDkoM (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'newsEvent', ... (11 bytes))
2022-09-22T18:33:11.788082-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: Received DISCONNECT from mosq-uQu5OKrc9nYuqKEN8A
2022-09-22T18:33:11.789566-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[4091]: Client mosq-uQu5OKrc9nYuqKEN8A disconnected.
```

The remote *.104 computer attempts connection over port 443 to Linux *.1 and succeeds,

```
PS C:\BROKER> $connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("192.168.2.1", "443")
 PS C:\BROKER> echo $connection.Connected
 True
```

Remote computer *.104 runs telnet through Cygwin.  telnet into to Linux *.1 port 22 responds correctly,

```
$ telnet
telnet> open 192.168.2.1 22
Trying 192.168.2.1...
Connected to 192.168.2.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
```

Telnet over 8883 fails.

```
$ telnet
telnet> open 192.168.2.1 8883
Trying 192.168.2.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
telnet>
```

TcpClient() into port 8883 fails.

```
$connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("192.168.2.1", "8883")
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
192.168.2.1:8883"
```

Publish from remote *.104 into local *.1 times out.

```
PS C:\BROKER\mosquitto> .\mosquitto_pub.exe -h 192.168.2.1 -p 8883 -t newsEvent -m "opti Payload"  -u redacted -P redacted
 Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

All the above were also tried using port 1883. Within the mosquitto.conf configuration file, I tried `user myUser` in replace of `user mosquit` , where `myUser` is the logged user running the broker. None of those changes fixed the problem. Attempts to contact the developers, Eclipse, through their forums yielded zero responses.